# how do i disable sql scripts showing up on the Powershell console while Restore?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have created a Powershell script that does mysql restore. It works fine only problem is that it shows sql scripts on the console which i want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

Use redirection to null to hide the output: > $null or mysql... | output-null